A thought on algorithm complexity?
I never have any formal trainings in algorithm, but I have read and watched some introductory material about the P=NP problem, which led me to make some conjectures based on my personal understanding of this topic.
Below is my conjecture:

If $P=NP$, then either $DTM=NTM$ or $L=NL=P=NP$

My rationale for this conjecture:

Non-deterministic turing machines(NTM) are supposed to solve
algorithms that contains branches of sub-algorithms; however, the
existence of branches means if each sub-algorithm(i.e. the algorithm
for each branch) requires $f(n)$ time to solve, then the algorithm
would require $2^{rf(n)}$ time to solve in the worst case, where $2^r$
is the total number of branches of the given algorithm.
Since a $NP$ problem means we need a polynomial time to check the
correctness of the solution, that means the sub-algorithm of a given
$NP$ problem would belong to the $P$ class. Therefore, if $P=NP$, then
either we only need a polynomial time to search all possible branches,
or the time required for each sub-algorithm in an $NP$-complete
algorithm would be of logarithmic time.
In the former case, this means the process of searching each branch
can be done in polynomial time, and this means a non-deterministic
turing machine is as effective as deterministic turing machine(DTM),
and a DTM can perfectly simulate a NTM, which implies that $DTM=NTM$.
In the latter case, as stated before, the sub-algorithm would be in
the $P$ class, which means we would find a logarithmic time for an
algorithm in the $P$ class. Since every algorithm in the same class
can be converted to another one in polynomial time, and the conversion
process is itself of an algorithm in the $P$ class, that means, every
algorithm in the $P$ class would be converted to a logarithmic time
algorithm in logarithmic time, thus we have $P=L$, and since $P=NP$ by
assumption, and since $L\subseteq NL\subseteq P$, this implies that
$L=NL=P=NP$ and thus we got a great collapse of complexity hierarchy!

Note that my conjecture is based on my limited understanding of the topic and some heuristic and possibly naive thoughts, there are no solid mathematics backing my thought, therefore I am not sure if my thoughts are right or not, nor am I sure if this is a stupid question or not.

This is looks like a solution verification question if I’m not wrong. For this type of question, you need specific which step in the proof is in doubt, and why so.
